# Hot to get parent node value using xdocument in c#?

Tags: c#, wcf, model-view-controller

I am creating MVC application in .Net, when I'm accessing WCF service using `xdocument`, I have a problem in getting value of parent node. How to do this?

Comment: We need code of what you have tried to properly help you *troubleshoot* the issue. If you haven't tried anything yet, *please give it an effort first* and then we may assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the name of parent node you can follow my example. Use your node name instead my `_Region`.

for my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<_Document_Definition>
    <_Regions>
        <_Region>
            <_Name>regionStaticTextTerminDii</_Name>
            <_Coordinates>
                <_X1>241</_X1>
                <_Y1>166</_Y1>
                <_X2>683</_X2>
                <_Y2>197</_Y2>
            </_Coordinates>
            <_BlockTypeEnum>BT_StaticText</_BlockTypeEnum>  
        </_Region>
        <_Region>
            <_Name>regionStaticTextExtension</_Name>
            <_Coordinates>
                <_X1>238</_X1>
                <_Y1>198</_Y1>
                <_X2>538</_X2>
                <_Y2>232</_Y2>
            </_Coordinates>
            <_BlockTypeEnum>BT_StaticText</_BlockTypeEnum>  
        </_Region>
    </_Regions>
</_Document_Definition>
```

I do next:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(docDifPath);
var infoRegions = from x in xDoc.Descendants("_Region")
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = x.Descendants("_Name").First().Value,
                        X1 = x.Descendants("_X1").First().Value,
                        Y1 = x.Descendants("_Y1").First().Value,
                        X2 = x.Descendants("_X2").First().Value,
                        Y2 = x.Descendants("_Y2").First().Value,
                        BlockTypeEnum = x.Descendants("_BlockTypeEnum").First().Value
                    };
//using obtaining info. I created Region class before
List<Region> regions = new List<Region>();
foreach (var i in infoRegions)
{
    Region region = new Region();
    region.name = i.Name;
    region.x1 = Convert.ToInt32(i.X1);
    region.y1 = Convert.ToInt32(i.Y1);
    region.x2 = Convert.ToInt32(i.X2);
    region.y2 = Convert.ToInt32(i.Y2);
    region.blockTypeEnumElem = (BlockTypeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(BlockTypeEnum), i.BlockTypeEnum);
    regions.Add(region);
}
```